# Sql Trigger - which table does it belong to?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

Is there a way within a Sql Server 2005 Trigger to get the name and schema of the table that the trigger is attached to during execution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_id) AS [Table],
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS TriggerName
FROM
    sys.triggers
WHERE
    object_id = @@PROCID
```

Then you can also use [OBJECTPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105.aspx) to get extra info, such as after/before, delete/insert/update, first/last etc

Answer (score 1):

This is a dirty way to know it

```
SELECT o.name
FROM sysobjects t
JOIN sysobjects o ON t.parent_obj = o.id
WHERE t.name = 'your_trigger_name'
```

**[EDIT]**

According to the other answer and the comments, i think this can fit to you (MSSQL2000 version)

```
SELECT o.name
FROM sysobjects t
JOIN sysobjects o ON t.parent_obj = o.id
WHERE t.id = @@PROCID
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the name of the trigger at runtime either.

Comment: You should avoid querying the system tables directly and use the system views instead.