# Is there a way to retrieve column name list from "magic" tables: insert and delete

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a trigger and from the trigger I need to access so called "magic table" insert but instead of data I need to retrieve a list of columns and table name. Is that possible? I did some research but could not find anything relevant. Would greatly appreciate a push in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Your question has to be solved step by step. The first step is to get the table name. Which you can get from the following solution, which uses `@@PROCID`.

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_id) AS [Table],
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS TriggerName
FROM
    sys.triggers
WHERE
    object_id = @@PROCID
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/727109/1339826

Then you can get the column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, like so:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Comment: in my case the table in question is the "inserted" table. It is not a regular table so I doubt I can get column names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Can I?

Comment: @ElenaDBA The inserted table is just a reference to the actual table. So by using that first step, you'll get the name of the real table. Then you can use that name to get the columns.